# Printing info using a WCF service

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, printing

I´m new to webservices, specially WCF´services but I´m handling it ok. My situation is the following one: I have a client app that calls the WCF services and obviusly, the WCF services. All is working as it should, but I need to print now, and thats where I´m stucked. What I want, is the client app to call a WCF service to print an invoice. I thought of using .rdlc reports for them. But I don´t have any idea of how can I passed them to the client app. As I say, what I need, is the pass all the info ready to print, so the client app cant change anything. Just print.

I need some help or advice of how to achieve this. If there is no other way, I may create the rdlc in the client app, but I really want to avoid this.

Just in case, my client app is a Winform app, and I´m using C#, Entity framework 4 and .NET 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your service convert the RDLC into a PDF and send the PDF as a byte array to yor WCF client. The client can then save the byte array as a .pdf file in the temporary file directory, and then ask the OS to launch the default application that registered for handling PDFs (acrobat,...).

As an example, here is the method I use in my MVVM viewmodel for a WPF client to download, save and launch a PDF report. The server sends a ReportDTO with the Report as a byte array, and FileName (report name with extension ".pdf"):

```
[DataContract(Name="ReportDTO", Namespace="http://chasmx/2013/2")]
public sealed class ReportDTO
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Filename to save the report attached in <see cref="@Report"/> under.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public String FileName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Report as a byte array.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public byte[] @Report { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Mimetype of the report attached in <see cref="@Report"/>. This can be used to launch the application registered for this mime type to view the saved report.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public String MimeType { get; set; }
}

public void ViewReport()
{
    ServiceContracts.DataContract.ReportDTO report;
    String filename;

    this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
    try
    {
        // Download the report.
        report = _reportService.GetReport(this.SelectedReport.ID);

        // Save the report in the temporary directory
        filename = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), report.FileName);
        try
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(filename, report.Report);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string detailMessage = "There was a problem saving the report as '" + filename + "': " + e.Message;
            _userInteractionService.AskUser(String.Format("Saving report to local disk failed."), detailMessage, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            return;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        this.Cursor = null;
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename); // The OS will figure out which app to open the file with.
}
```

That lets you keep all report definitions on the server and dumbs the WCF interface to your client down to supplying a PDF byte array.

Comment: Yes I thought of doing something like this, do you know how can I make the client to open the PDF automatically? If you can give me some code example the better! And thanks, you are the second person to told me to do it this way, so maybe thats the solution!